# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying fetch data from oracle database. I getting this error  `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments`

here is my **Profile** class

```
public class Profile
    {
         public string PROF_TEXT  {set; get;}
         public string PROF_EMPL {set; get;} 
         public string PROF_NNAM {set; get;} 
         public string PROF_FNAM {set; get;} 
         public string PROF_MNAM {set; get;}  
         public string PROF_PADD   {set; get;}
         public string PROF_RADD   {set; get;}
         public string PROF_PPHN   {set; get;}
         public string PROF_HPHN   {set; get;}
         public string PROF_PNID   {set; get;}
         public string PROF_MAIL   {set; get;}
         public string PROF_REFR  {set; get;}
         public string PROF_RMRK  {set; get;}
         public string PROF_GEND  {set; get;}
         public string PROF_MARD  {set; get;}
         public string PROF_ACTV  { set; get; }
    }
```

second class **ProfileDB** for connecting with database

```
public class ProfileDB
    {
        private OracleConnection conn;
        private OracleCommand cmd;
        private OracleDataAdapter oda;
        private DataSet ds;
        string strComm;

        public   List<Profile> ListAll()   
        {
            try
            {
                List<Profile> lst = new List<Profile>();
                conn = new OracleConnection(clsConnection.ConnectionSave);
                conn.Open();
                strComm = "SELECT * FROM PROFILE";
                cmd = new OracleCommand(strComm, conn);
                oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                oda.Fill(lst);
                conn.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                return lst;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and connection class

```
public class clsConnection
    {
        public OracleConnection oConn;

        public clsConnection()
        {

        }

        public static string ConnectionSave
        {
            get
            {
                string oradb = "Data Source=try; User Id=try; Password =try123";
                return oradb;

            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting error here **oda.Fill(lst);** mention in title. Here is the database column

[image: Databse image].

I am very new in .net. I want to use classes for connecting with databse. Could dome help me for solving error. I know it silly but as new can not get the solution. Thank you in advance. Please let me know any other information needed.

Comment: If you want to use classes, your best option is to use an ORM, e.g. Entity Framework. Currently, you're doing it in a good-old ADO.NET way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `Fill` method to fill a `List<T>`, you have to pass it a `DataSet` object.  Then you can query tables that object (or iterate through it) and load your `List`.  Something like this:

```
oda.Fill(ds);
conn.Dispose();
conn.Close();

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    lst.Add(/* however you create your profile instance */);
}
```

Comment: It really works for me . Could you please tell how to bind date in the  model, If **Prof_Bday = row["prof_bday"].to_string()** but I am getting this error **cannot implicitly covert type 'string' to 'System.dateTime'**